# Webelement object python variable not recognized by intellisense

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I am new to python and web scraping with selenium. I was following a tutorial and I noticed in the tutorial, when Tim referenced the Webelement object intellisense listed all the possible functions. However when I was following the tutorial my webelement object did not return any methods and intellisense did not recognize the options. I am using most recent version of python verison 3.9.6 pip version 21.2.3 Selenium version 3.141.0

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "localpath"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
HTTPS = "https://"

# hard coded data to test 
siteDomain = "indeed.com"
jobSearch = "Entry Level Software Developer"
locationSearch = "Richmond, VA"

# Goes to Site
driver.get(HTTPS + siteDomain)

# obtains access to elements from website 
searchJob = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
searchLocation = driver.find_element_by_name("l")

# clear text field
searchJob.clear()
searchLocation.clear()

# inputs values into website elements
searchJob.send_keys(jobSearch)
searchLocation.send_keys(locationSearch)

# presses button to search
searchLocation.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.quit()
```

when I do driver.xxx I get the intellisense auto fill options. When I try to use the objects searchJob and searchLocation I do not get the intellisense auto fill options. I manually type out searchJob.send_keys(jobSearch) searchLocation.send_keys(locationSearch). Also element.clear() is also not working as I believe the problem is the same. I would like to see the options to better understand more complex problems. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: VSCode @MattDMo

Answer (score 1):

For your problem with element.clear() the following subsitution worked for me

```
searchLocation.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```

Which is just saying select everything with control a and then delete it. If you're on a mac you might need to do COMMAND or something like that.

I had the same problem with IntelliSense when I reproduce what you did in VSC. I then tried it in Pycharm CE2021 and had IntelliSense work well. If you are not too attached to VSC then you might want to try Pycharm as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

The Intellisense was provided by the `Pylance Language Server` by default. You can switch to another language server, such as `JediLSP`.

Add this in the `settings.json` file:

```
"python.languageServer": "JediLSP",
```